# Upload, compress and serve video with AWS

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I am creating as my own project a mobile app. One of the functionalities of the application is uploading video files (up to 500mb) and watching uploaded videos by other users.

I was thinking about various server solutions and how many people have so many opinions. Unfortunately, it is hard for me to find someone among my friends who knows the topic well and would be able to advise. For the beginning, I think it makes sense to use AWS (but I've never done it) and I would like to ask you (if I can) for advice.

1. In step one I upload a video file to AWS S3 via the application
2. AWS MediaConverter compresses the video file, the old one is removed and replaced with a new one (Elastic Transcoder is very expensive)
3. In the application, I can paste direct links to s3 which I can use to serve videos.

As far as I understand, I don't need any other services than AWS S3 and AWS MediaConverter.

Or maybe I am thinking wrong and using amazon for this does not make sense?

Thanks!

Comment: AWS can do all of this, of course, but I think your decisions are going to be based largely on what scale you need and what a reasonable cost is. Understand the various pricing models, especially for network egress to your users. Delivering video from S3/CloudFront is likely the biggest cost here. For small scale usage, you might also consider using something simple like ffmpeg to convert video formats, depending on what it would cost to use a managed service like AWS MediaConverter.